# Как в Veeam для backup job указать нужный прокси?

Tags: proxy

Здравствуйте.

У меня имеется veeam Backup & Replication 8.

Есть несколько территориально разнесённых серверов, виртуалки с которых нужно бэкапить. Бэкапить нужно не через управляющий сервер. Прокси veeam проинсталлированы. Теперь вопрос - как в джобе указать, какой именно для данного задания использовать прокси сервер veeam?